# Are there other features like "Jack of All Trades" or "Remarkable Athlete"?

Tags: dnd-5e, proficiency

Long story short, I'm working on an editable, self-updating Spreadsheet/Character Sheet. I want to incorporate features like Jack of All Trades or Remarkable Athlete that apply a portion of a character's proficiency bonus to various ability checks. Basically, there would be a check box labeled "Jack of All Trades" that, when checked, would apply half proficiency bonus rounded down to all non proficient ability checks on the character sheet (including initiative). Same idea for Remarkable Athlete (but round up and Str/Dex only).

Are there any other features like these that basically only add some or all of proficiency bonus to all instances of an ability check (so Dwarven Stonecunning wouldn't count) other than Proficiency, Expertise, Jack of All Trades or Remarkable Athlete?

Comment: Do you ask about class features only?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already.

Comment: Would also be interested in Race Features, enkryptor

Comment: Are you only looking for features which add proficiency bonus to certain things? Or are you looking for every feature that adds anything to any number on your character sheet?

Comment: That's a great question, Rubiksmoose. On some thought, I'm going to narrow down to anything that adds full or partial proficiency to all instances of ability checks that aren't proficiency, expertise, Jack of All Trades or Remarkable Athlete.

Answer (score 6):

No.

There are many class and race features in 5e that modify some specific checks, but the only features (currently) that specifically target non-proficient checks, and add half-proficiency, are the two that you have already listed. I am stating this based off of all published 5e material currently (that is, not counting any Unearthed Arcana or other play testing material).